# How to change cursor in VSCode?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have been using VScode in Ubuntu 20.04. My cursor has changed to box cursor which was normal line cursor previously. It's irretating me badly every time I open a new file and behaving exactly same as Vim cursor.

Please help me to change the settings, so that want to get the old normal cursor of VS code.

I have tried uninstalling the VSCode, deleted the Code folder in `~/.config/Code` and reinstall the VS Code. But, still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the vim extension installed. Go to the extension pane and search for vim:

[image]

You can either disable the extension or uninstall it.